# Tough spot with Aces against regular, NLHE-6max

Tags: nlhe, cash-game, hand-history, home-game

6max Nlhe, home-game, blinds are 0.5/1, deepstack (everyone approximately ~350 stack)

Villain is a very experienced and regular winning player, very tricky, capable of unorthodox plays as well. We have played around 100 hands during the night. We don't have a particular history between us, other than he considers to be more experienced than me. Generally, my image is tight, and that night in particular rock-like player.

1. Pre flop  Villain raises to 3.5 from early position.
   I re-raise from
   Dealer Button with  A⋄A♥ to 12
   Everyone folds and the
   villain calls (pot~25, our stacks~340)
2. Flop comes A♠K♠7♠

   Villain bets quickly 20, I re-raise to 60, he thinks for about 1
   minute and calls (looks like he was thinking to raise in my opinion)

   (pot~145,our stacks~280)
3. Turn comes 6♥.  Pretty much a blank.

   He quickly checks. I bet 70 and he snap calls.

   (pot~280, our stacks~210)
4. River comes 2♠ putting a 4 flush on the board.

   He takes some time and bets only 60

---

What should I do?
I was between folding and calling obviously, but I want to hear your thoughts as to how I played the hand generally (given the info) and for the final decision.

PS. I will give the results later ;)

---

Results:

> I called relatively fast, just the way Dr.DrfbagIII described. My
>  Opponent held AK, just top two pairs, without any flush. He was
>  shocked he was beat at the end, he put me on a hand type like AQ
>  through the entire hand and at the end he was thin value betting, at
>  least that's what he told me. In the flop, he told me he was thinking
>  of re-raising with the intention of getting his entire stack in, but
>  he decided to play it a bit slower, since we were pretty deep-stack. I
>  found the hand very interesting that's why I posted it, although I
>  think I could have got more value in such a spot (top-set vs top two
>  pair).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preflop is standard and flop is fine.  At that point, the only hand that beats you is a flopped flush and even then you have a strong re-draw to a full house.

On the turn, I'd bet more.  Your hand has a lot of value but is vulnerable with one card to come--charge him more to see a river.  The issue with a bigger raise though, say 100, is that it sets up a situation where any re-raise by him will be a situation where you're playing for stacks right then; but that's something to worry about if/when it actually happens, for now a bigger bet seems better.

It's interesting that he quickly bets the flop and considers re-raising it (in your opinion), but then doesn't take the opportunity to check-raise the turn.  He likely knows you're going to bet, so with a flopped flush that would seem to be an obvious move.  That leads me to believe he does not have a flush at this point.  Some possibilities for his hands would be AK (not too likely since 3 aces are out), a set of 7's, or the Q of spades--maybe with an A, J, or 10 which would make the hand appear even stronger.

The river sucks of course.  His small bet looks like one of two things: either a small value bet (probably w/ Qs) because you're not likely to call more or to bet yourself OR a type of blocking bet.  If he did have AK or 77, the last thing he wants to face is a good size bet from you after he checks, and he knows that's what he'd be facing quite often.  He wants a cheap showdown, so he bets small--if you raise, he knows he's beat, and if you fold that's fine from his perspective too.

With the pot odds you're getting, you only need to win >15% of the time to make this a call.  I'd expect to lose most of the time, but since there is that chance of him making the blocking bet I describe (and a small chance he's on an elaborate bluff), I'd make a crying call.  The other benefit is more of a meta-game consideration: if he or the other players see how easily you fold in that situation, you might face more bets down the road on scary boards.  I think it's close, but you also get the information about what the opponent had when you call so that's what I'd do, fully prepared to start going on a rant about how everything is rigged :)

Comment: Agree with all your points 100%, my thoughts exactly.
As for the turn, I didn't bet a lot firstly to keep his marginal hands in and secondly not to become commited in case he had a flush and reraised me.
Hadn't he bet in the river, I would have checked back hoping for a good showdown.

Answer (score 2):

You flop the second nuts on what is still a very scary board for you. I think you need to play it more aggressively than you did.

Not likely either of you hit a flush on the flop as you would not play spade combo that way.  Villain might be on QJs or JTs but that would be a pretty lose open pre. AK is block to Ax and Kx.

Villain would have 3 bet pre with KK.  Maybe 3 bet with QQ.

There is also a straight draw - they *could* be on QJs, QTs, or JTs.

Spade is less in your range as you are likely on TT+ or AK and only 3 spades there - you would have just called pre with a suited combo.  Where I put villain on any pair and there is only one AK left and they *could* be on a loose suited combo play.

Flop villain donks for almost the pot. A spade should just check. They could be on AK or 77 wanting a fold or build value and hope a spade does not hit. Or they could be on a pocket pair with no spade taking a shot at taking down the pot.

On the flop I think you should have re-raised to $80-$100 to try and get a fold from a small spade or max value if villain has 77 or AK.  There is a 35% chance a spade hits by the river that does not give you a boat. When they call $60 they likely have 77, AK, or a spade (but you don't know how big).

They would not check the turn with a made flush. I think you need to apply more pressure on the turn but they were not getting direct odds to call a flush draw.  You were getting close to pot committed if you bet $100. The hands you want to call (AK, 77) would still call $100.

If you had bet $80-$100 on the flop you would be pot committed on the turn and need to jam to that blank. I am not putting them on made a flush and you would get a call from 77 and AK and should fold out a single spade (maybe not the queen) and a straight draw. It is only 1/5.5 that a spade hits on the river that does not give you a boat. Even a made flush you have 10 outs - 22% equity. Thing is if no spade hits you are still going to get value from 77 or AK on the river but I still think $80 flop and jam a blank turn is your best EV here.

Obviously a spade on the river is a bad card for you. That is not a bluff. That is a value bet or a blocking bet afraid you have a bigger spade. Jam and try to represent QQ with a spade would not be a good plan. I would call as you are getting over 5:1 but you are probably beat by a pair with a spade. About the only hands that you beat are 77 and AK and they could have played that way.

I agree with Dr.Drfbaglll you also need to call to not be let others see you fold easily.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to hear your thoughts as to how I played the hand generally

**Preflop** : standard -> good

**Flop** : standard -> not bad
 - here, I narrow his *possible* range down to :

Ac-Qs / Ac-Js / Js-Jx / Ts-Tx / 7-7 (less likely JT with a spades / any 2 - air)

His *quick $20 bet* could be done to show some strength, impress you, protect his hand. When he took time to think, I think he was trying to read your hand more than playing with your nerves.

**It's now a pretty standard WA/WB hand**

**Turn** : standard, you keep your logic.

**River** : is he making a value bet or a blocking bet ? Either way, he's put you in trouble, facing a tough decision. Question is: are you facing any spades he's holding (if so, is it a small/big one) ?

> I want to hear your thoughts [...] for the final decision.

60:340 -> 5.5:1 -> **call**

Now, in that spot, with information given, I would have, from the flop, acted differently :

- flop: bet -> cold call
- turn: check -> check (bet ? cold call)
- river: ??? (depending on his move)

But then, on the river, with more clues, I might have gone with : check ? check. bet ? 2.5 raise, in order to put him under pressure, and have him scared that you hold a higher spades, or any spades if he has none (worth trying, no ? ^^)
If he raises again, then you know almost for sure...

That way, I would have neither given a strong hint about my hand nor find myself pot-committed.

Better win (lose ?) a small pot than lose a big one ?

Comment: Pretty standard play to not give a draw pot odds.  Especially if the draw is the only hand that can beat you.

Comment: I agree. I thought that way because OP said `very tricky, capable of unorthodox plays as well`. Therefore, you can also try and play different. Villain may have got in with 8s/9s. As I see the WA/WB from flop, I may play different, non-standard moves, and try not to be pot committed.

Comment: Not putting villain on 8s/9s coming in for 3.5 early and calling 12.   Made flush would have bet the turn.

Comment: bet the turn, yes, but he may also think hero gets a higher spades. OP said `Villain bets quickly 20, I re-raise to 60, he thinks for about 1 minute and calls`. From there, imagine Villain dosen't think about a raise, but rather puts Hero on AxQs ? He may want to put as little money as he can.

Comment: I agree we won't agree :) but I always take advice of all comments as they  help in a way or another ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61304/discussion-between-paparazzi-and-oldpadawan).